# Kotlin how get width of wrap_content TextView

Tags: android, kotlin, width

I have a problem, because I need to have width of my TextView. I have already width of my Layout, but I need to have a width of specific element too. In this case TextView. I'm trying to get it, but I think that addOnLayoutChangeListener is going on another scope or sth because when I try to assign width to var textWidth I can't do this and variable return 0, but in println I can see that there is a value which I need. How can I get this value?

```
           var textWidth = 0

           textViewOne.addOnLayoutChangeListener {
                v, left, top, right, bottom, oldLeft, oldTop, oldRight, oldBottom
                -> textWidth = right-left
                println("${right-left}") <-- this return 389
            }
    
            println("${textWidth}") <-- this return 0
```

Any tips how to do take width of TextView?

Comment: In what scope this code is executed? `onCreateView` or `onCreate` or something else?

Comment: Everything is onCreate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solved problem if anyone need solution this workes for me:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    val displayMetrics: DisplayMetrics = applicationContext.resources.displayMetrics
    val pxWidth = displayMetrics.widthPixels

    val baseLayout = findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.baseLayout)

    baseLayout.doOnLayout {
        val textViewOne = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textVieOne)
        val oneWidth = textViewOne.width

        val textViewTwo = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textViewTwo)
        val twoWidth = textViewTwo.width

        val textViewThree = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textViewThree)
        val threeWidth = textViewThree.width

        val sumOfChildWidths = oneWidth + twoWidth + threeWidth
        
        if(pxWidth <= sumOfChildWidths){
            textViewThree.isVisible = false
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the views dimensions are not evaluated at this stage so you don’t have a choice but to wait until the layout is fully rendered.

Assuming you are not measuring a single view, I’d recommend attaching `OnGlobalLayoutListener` to the root view:

```
rootView.viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener {
    // Do your thing
}
```

And if you want the code to be executed only once:

```
rootView.viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(object : OnGlobalLayoutListener {
    override fun onGlobalLayout() {
        rootView.viewTreeObserver.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this)
        // Do your thing
    }
})
```